# Count of Value from the Given Date time + 1Hour

Tags: sql, timestamp

I have a Dataset like:

```
Date - Time Dimension1  Dimension2  Count
10-1-2020 00:18:15  A   B   2
10-1-2020 01:18:00  A   B   3
10-1-2020 01:45:00  A   B   2
10-1-2020 01:48:00  A   B   1
10-1-2020 03:02:00  B   A   5
```

The DateTime column that we see in the Dataset has 2 dimensions and the final display is the count of values with respect to the Date Time + 1Hour.

```
Record 1 : Given Date : 01/10/2020 12:18:15 AM  Date + 1Hour : 01/10/2020 01:18:15 AM
```

So between these 2 dates I need to find out the count of matching records. For this date range there are 2 records which are within 1 hour so the count is 2.

Code :

```
SELECT
D5,
CAL_DATE,
Transaction_DATETIME,
D1,
D2,
D3,
D4,
COUNT(D4) AS CNT
FROM TAB1
WHERE 
timestamp(Transaction_DATETIME, 'MM-D-YYYY HH:mm:ss TT') >= timestamp(Transaction_DATETIME, 'MM-D-YYYY HH:mm:ss TT')
AND timestamp(Transaction_DATETIME, 'MM-D-YYYY HH:mm:ss TT') <= Timestamp(Transaction_DATETIME + Time#('01:00:00','HH:mm:ss'),'MM-D-YYYY HH:mm:ss TT')
GROUP By
D5,
DATE,
Transaction_DATETIME,
D1,
D2,
D3,
D4;
```

Requesting your help on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Your code is not quite valid SQL.  And your question is quite unclear.  What are you trying to calculate?

Comment: I am calculating the count of transaction which occured between the timestamp and timestamp + 1hr and that scenario should be calculated for all the timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL supports window functions for this purpose.  In many databases, the syntax is something like this:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by dim1, dim2
                      order by datetime
                      range between current row and interval '1 hour' following
                     ) as cnt
from t;
```

Not all databases support window functions with range on intervals.  In those, a subquery is needed:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.dim1 = t.dim1 and t2.dim2 = t.dim2 and
              t2.datetime >= t.datetime and
              t2.datetime < t.datetime + interval '1 hour'
       ) as cnt
from t;
```

Once again, note that date/time functions notoriously vary among databases.  The above is standard SQL but may need to be tweaked for your database.

Comment: Hi Gordon, For the same query above I want to display the count as 0 for the datatime which are already been considered. For Example , second records already falls in the interval of the first record so I dont want to calculate the value for 2 nd records as it is already considered. Please help.

Comment: @Ishan . . . I would suggest you ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation.